# Trouble configuring a printer

Tags: printing, hp

I have a HP Deskjet 1055 I tried to enhance the print quality a while ago by using the proprieraty driver provided in HPLIP and it stopped working. I'm trying to print a test page and it keeps on "processing" forever, if I look at the job, it is "pending" and the printer power light stay in the sleeping state. The driver say HP-Deskjet-1050-J410 Series. Any idea on how to get the printer working?

Some info requested by @N0rbert

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS \n \l

$ dpkg -s hplip
Package: hplip
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: utils
Installed-Size: 1563
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 3.17.10+repack0-5
```

Comment: To few information. What is your Ubuntu version? How did you installed HPLIP? According to the [official HPLIP page you need version >= 3.10.6 without proprietary plugin](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index). Which HPLIP version do you use?

Comment: The mentioned missing info is now in the Question. Thanks N0rbert.

Comment: It seems that you are using HPLIP from official repositories. It is correct and enough to get setup the printer. You can try to launch `hp-doctor` to detect hidden software problems.

Comment: I switched the question to [launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/hplip/+question/678205) as it does seem more appropriate to file a bug than ask a question to users. Thanks for leading me there @N0rbert.